# switching from Xalan to Saxon

Tags: xslt, saxon, xalan

Getting error while saxon parser parsing saxon:evaluate function.

This exception I am getting:

```
 XPST0003: Static error in XPath expression supplied to saxon:evaluate: Unexpected token
  "<eof>" in path expression
net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Static error in XPath expression supplied to saxon:evaluate: Unexpected token "<eof>" in path expression
    at com.saxonica.functions.extfn.Evaluate$EvaluateCall.prepareExpression(Evaluate.java:223)
    at com.saxonica.functions.extfn.Evaluate$EvaluateCall.call(Evaluate.java:263)
    at net.sf.saxon.functions.IntegratedFunctionCall.call(IntegratedFunctionCall.java:298)
    at CE__Slash__29499086.process(file:/D:/WORKS/WORKS_ON_XSLT2.0/Test.xsl:48)
    at com.saxonica.bytecode.CompiledExpression.process(CompiledExpression.java:60)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Template.applyLeavingTail(Template.java:214)
    at net.sf.saxon.trans.Mode.applyTemplates(Mode.java:1034)
    at net.sf.saxon.Controller.transformDocument(Controller.java:1957)
    at net.sf.saxon.Controller.transform(Controller.java:1803)
    at com.iflex.fcat.gui.content.TestXMLXSLTContentGenerator.simpleTransform(TestXMLXSLTContentGenerator.java:177)
    at com.iflex.fcat.gui.content.TestXMLXSLTContentGenerator.main(TestXMLXSLTContentGenerator.java:190)
```

Comment: can you post exactly what is getting passed into the `evaluate` function?

Comment: @ColinD it is giving exception when we are parsing null string or invalid xpath.

Comment: saxon:evaluate() is designed to throw a dynamic error if given a zero length string or a string that is not a valid XPath exception. The product is behaving as designed. If you can tell us what you want to achieve we can perhaps hep you achieve it. (Please note that we make to guarantee to see or answer Saxon questions posted on StackOverflow. If you want to be sure of an answer, use the support forums at dev.saxonica.com.)

Comment: @MichaelKay Thanks for your useful comment.Can you please elaborate us how can i catch that particular exception in xslt or how can i avoid that particular exception in my xslt code.

Comment: To catch dynamic errors in XSLT you need the XSLT 3.0 try/catch facility, which is implemented in the commercial editions of Saxon 9.4.